# Problem with toolbar in Excel 2003

Tags: excel, localization, vsto, add-in

I have a very simple Excel Addin build it in Visual Studio 2008 for Excel 2003, which creates a toolbar with some buttons.

When I debug it, with System Format set to "English (United States)" it works great, without problems.

However, this addin is going to be used with System Format set to "French (France)" too, and when I try to debug my addin under this configuration, the toolbar (which is created by the addin) is not being shown.

While I'm debugging I can see that the methods that create the toolbar are executed and the code returns fine, yet I can't see anything in Excel, and if I switch back the format to English it works again.

Does anyone know which could be the reason?

Comment: Aren't you using some "magic string" in your addin?

Comment: no I'm not, in fact I created another project from scratch, with a toolbar an a single button and it happens the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, there was a problem related with the decimal separator, which changes for French language, and a validation that I was doing in my code, I missed that part when debugging, thanks for the answers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with an add-in that I built for Excel 2000.  Although the tool bar would show, nothing was on the toolbar.  I was able to correct the issue by downloading the 
office multilanguage pack 2003.

Here is a link to it, assuming you do not already have this installed it may be worth a shot.
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/ork2003/HA011402201033.aspx

Comment: thanks for the help but it seems that it is something else, I installed the multilingual package and yet is not working...